# element in R dataframe good practice

Tags: r, dataframe, brackets, dollar-sign

Accessing the `i`th element in the column `bar` in the dataframe `foo` in R can be done in two different ways:

`foo[i,"bar"]`

and

`foo$bar[i]`.

Is there any difference between them? If so, which one should be used in terms of efficiency, readability, etc.?

Apologies if this has already been asked, but `[]` and  `$` characters are very elusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to think this is an opinion based question, and therefore inappropriate for SO. But since you ask for speed considerations, I won't flag it as such. Note: There are more than the two methods you describe for indexing...

```
data(mtcars)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(opt_a= mtcars$disp[12],
           opt_b= mtcars[12, "disp"],
           opt_c= mtcars[["disp"]][12])

Unit: microseconds
  expr   min      lq     mean  median     uq     max neval cld
 opt_a 5.322  6.4620  8.34029  6.8425  7.603  56.640   100  a 
 opt_b 9.503 10.0735 15.41463 10.6435 11.024 354.285   100   b
 opt_c 4.181  4.942  7.77386  5.322  6.082 84.009   100     a
```

using `foo$bar[i]` appears to be considerably faster than `foo[i, "bar"]` but not the fastest alternative